# All Day Events start the day before?

Tags: calendar

I have a calendar view, which I have set as a list, and I filter it so that "uncompleted items" pop up for that day.  This is very useful for giving my team an easy visual of items that still need to be completed, without having to click on individual events, as you would in a regular calendar view.  However, one issue that comes up is that when there's an "all day event," it registers that event as starting the day before.  It starts at 12:00 am, and SharePoint seems to read that as that still belonging to the previous day.  I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with this so that "all day events" can register on the day they're meant to.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the time zone on your server match the time zone on your client?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately All Day Events are 12am to 11:59pm in Zulu/GMT but get converted to the local time zone for the user. The only solution I can think of is to create a secondary start and end date/time, set them with a workflow if it's an all day event, and hide them by creating a custom content type excluding the new fields. Unfortunately, the number of hours added/subtracted would have to be changed in the workflow twice a year to account for daylight savings. And of course this won't work if you have users in various time zones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I've decided for now to simply have "All day events" equal to "No" on the filter.

Comment: Another thing you could do quickly is set a workflow to uncheck All Day Event and set the start and end time to 8am - 5pm or something like that.